# Parallel Fortran Program Crash

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I have some code that has been optimized and parallelized with OpenMP.
The code works fine with small datasets (tested with 4,000 datapoints) but fails with larger datasets (tested with 12,000 datapoints). I compiled with gfortran (gcc 4.9.3) on Windows 7 under Cygwin.

The program reads data into arrays and calculates some statistics using parameters from an input parameter file:

```
  real,allocatable         :: x(:),y(:),z(:),vr(:,:),azm(:),atol(:),
 +                            bandwh(:),dip(:),dtol(:),bandwd(:)
  real*8,allocatable       :: sills(:),dis(:),gam(:),hm(:),
 +                            tm(:),hv(:),tv(:),np(:)
  integer,allocatable      :: ivtail(:),ivhead(:),ivtype(:)
  character*12,allocatable :: names(:)
```

Here are user defined parameters to run the program

```
  real      EPSLON,VERSION
  real      xlag,xltol,tmin,tmax
  integer   nd,nlag,ndir,nvarg,isill,test
  character outfl*512
```

This section is related to OpenMP. There are definitions of reduced varaibles for OpenMP.

```
  parameter(PI=3.14159265)
  real      uvxazm(100),uvyazm(100),uvzdec(100),
 +          uvhdec(100),csatol(100),csdtol(100)
  logical   omni
  integer   threadId,numThreads
  real*8,allocatable ::    reducedVariables(:,:,:)
  integer extractValue
  integer i,j,id,ii,il,it,iv,jj
  real dx,dy,dz,dxs,dys,dzs,hs,h
  integer lagbeg,lagend,ilag
  real band,dcazm,dcdec,dxy,gamma,vrh,vrhpr,vrt,vrtpr
  real xi,yi,zi
  integer liminf,limsup,iinf,isup,k
  real xlaginv
```

The main parallel loop is called here:

```
c$omp parallel default(firstprivate)
c$omp& shared(x,y,z,reducedVariables,vr)
#ifdef _OPENMP
      threadId = int(OMP_get_thread_num())+1
      print *,'Thread ',threadId
#else
      threadId = 1   
#endif
```

This section recombines the variables:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP

c$omp barrier
      reducedVariables(1,:,threadId)=dis(:)
      reducedVariables(2,:,threadId)=gam(:)
      reducedVariables(3,:,threadId)=np(:)
      reducedVariables(4,:,threadId)=hm(:)
      reducedVariables(5,:,threadId)=tm(:)
      reducedVariables(6,:,threadId)=hv(:)
      reducedVariables(7,:,threadId)=tv(:)
#endif



c$omp end parallel

#ifdef _OPENMP
      dis(:)=0.0
      gam(:)=0.0
      np(:)=0.0
      hm(:)=0.0
      tm(:)=0.0
      hv(:)=0.0
      tv(:)=0.0
      do ii=1,numThreads
         do jj=1,mxdlv
            dis(jj) = dis(jj) + reducedVariables(1,jj,ii)
            gam(jj) = gam(jj) + reducedVariables(2,jj,ii)
            np(jj)  = np(jj)  + reducedVariables(3,jj,ii)
            hm(jj)  = hm(jj)  + reducedVariables(4,jj,ii)
            tm(jj)  = tm(jj)  + reducedVariables(5,jj,ii)
            hv(jj)  = hv(jj)  + reducedVariables(6,jj,ii)
            tv(jj)  = tv(jj)  + reducedVariables(7,jj,ii)
         end do
      end do
    #endif
```

I've debugged with gdb and get the following error:

> At line 894 of file gamv.fpp Fortran runtime error: Index '13' of
>   dimension 1 of array 'np' above upper bound of 12
>
> [Thread 9336.0x1494 exited with code 2] [Thread 9336.0x22f4 exited
>   with code 2] [Inferior 1 (process 9336) exited with code 02]

The offending section of code:

```
if(it.eq.1.or.it.eq.5.or.it.ge.9) then
do il=lagbeg,lagend
ii = (id-1)*nvarg*(nlag+2)+(iv-1)*(nlag+2)+il
np(ii)  = np(ii)  + 1.
dis(ii) = dis(ii) + dble(h)
tm(ii)  = tm(ii)  + dble(vrt)
hm(ii)  = hm(ii)  + dble(vrh)
gam(ii) = gam(ii) + dble((vrh-vrt)*(vrh-vrt))
end do
```

I don't see anywhere that array `np` was defined as having an upper bound of 12.

Is this an issue with using dynamic arrays with OpenMP?

Comment: You say you can't see where `np` was given an upper bound of 12, but it must have been given something somewhere (I hope).  Is there no `allocate` statement or some other assignment which allocates it that you haven't shown us?  [If there isn't, then that's a big enough problem.]

Comment: compiling with `-fcheck=all` and / or running the code through valgrind might be a good idea...